# How do I customize the Subject View for my SharePoint Community?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, view, discussion-board, community-site

**TLDR:** Is there a way to change the UI for the default Subject View for SharePoint discussion forums? I've gone into SharePoint designer and changed the `ReadOnly` attribute of the view to `FALSE`, but all that unlocks for me in the web client is the ability to add columns, change positions / sorting order, etc., which seemingly does nothing to change how the Subject View looks or behaves.

--

I maintain a SharePoint publishing site for my team, and it has been a useful way to quickly publish and iterate on walkthroughs, reference materials, and other help content for our customers. A new goal along the lines of customer support is to build a self-serving community, which is why our team decided to add a discussion board to our SharePoint publishing site.

The discussion board is there to support two scenarios: firstly, general discussion, and secondly, feature voting. The first scenario is simple enough, but the second scenario - allowing customers to submit and vote for features - presents some challenges. We'd like to use the discussion board's built-in rating feature to drive feature voting, but that comes with the challenge of making "voting" (actually measured in "Likes") more discoverable.

With the default Subject View, visitors can see a list of discussion titles, authors, # of votes, etc. I'd like to add a voting button, a clickable "Like", to the default view, so visitors won't have to click into the topic and click "Like". Ultimately, getting the same functionality - though not necessarily UI - as UserVoice would be pretty awesome:

[image: Feature voting through UserVoice]

For reference, this is the current, default Subject View:

[image: Default subject view for discussion forum]

To vote, visitors must click the title link to see the discussion topic, and click Like on that page:

[image: Discussion topic "Like" button]

Comment: Have you tried Surveys?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just looked at Surveys. That could be one way to tackle feature voting, but it looks like there is the same problem of needing to create a custom list view with a "Like" button. I realized that my post was a bit sparse in details, so I've added some pictures to help illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.